# How can I connect multiple lamps to a single cable?

Tags: electrical

I have 5 lamps, which I want to attach to a single power cord. If it was only 1 or 2, I'd just plug the wires into an insulating screw joint like these:

[image]

But 5 cables are just too thick. How should I do it properly?

Comment: What kinds of lamps? AC, DC? Low-voltage? Incandescent, halogen, CFL, LED? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: @alt AC CFL from what I understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot of approaches there. This solution is not the most pretty but is effective. If the only problem is the amount of wires you can set several joints in a row as in picture (sorry about that picture, was the best I could to this quick)

[image: Not the most pretty join job]

You can also use a screw press line cap

[image: less ugly]

I would recommend to keep that joint inside a electrical joint box. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you're going to use twist-on wire connectors, make sure you get the proper size for the number and size of wires you're connecting.  If you're using screw terminals in the way described above, make sure each terminal is rated to accept multiple wires of the size wire you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I connected 6 LED lights plus 1 LAMP on a ceiling fascia.

Here’s how:
Problem: Purchased two “one-to-one” connector for 8 circuits from HD. The clerk told me that I connect the main box live wire black to one connector and white to the second connector. These would be connected to any one screw on each set as input. Then connect the 8 black output wires to the 8 screws on the other line of screws. Do the same for the white set. Wrong! The piece requires one input for each output. I corrected the situation by welding the 8 black and 8 white to individual metal plates and connected to each lamp (black/white). Then welded a black wire input and white wire input at each plate and connected to the box. It can become quite a mess of wires if you are not careful and neat. The assembly goes toward the ceiling so the wires are totally invisible.